# Macro or app script for autoreplace pasted data

Tags: google-sheets

Is there are any chance to have such script, that perform replace of "pasted data" to any cell of column B to "abc"+"pasted data"?

Comment: I think that in your situation, OnEdit simple trigger can be used. And, I thought that these threads might be useful for understanding for creating a script. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37286851 https://stackoverflow.com/q/58378575 https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820952

Answer (score 0):

while there is a script for what you request until you get one try this in C1 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B:B);;"""abc""+"""&B:B&""""))
```